# Swift 1.2 UICollectionViewController if statement with UICollectionViewCell Image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I’m trying to put an if statement beside cell.albumimage.image but it says cannot assign a value of type “ UIImage? “ if i write this code :

```
if cell.AlbumImage.image = "1433499137_settings_ios7_ios_7.png"{
            
    }
```

if I write this code, Xcode says

> Cannot assign a value of type “UIImage?

I’m working on UICollectionViewController. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator assign (=) instead of equals (==).

Comment: Using that operator gives the error Use of local variable "cell" before its declaration

Comment: In that case it would be good if you could post more of your code to see what is happening there. And what is the intention of the if statement?